# what's the purpose of dynamicStage and dynamicAlwaysScript keywords

Tags: jenkins

Good afternoon community,

It's always a pleasure to get any feedbacks from SO. I have a jenkins build that is configure based on a 'groovy' file containing a set of stages to execute

I noticed it contains the keywords `dynamicStage(<stage name>)` followed by `dynamicAlwaysScript`

example (snippet)

```
pipeline{
  stages{
    stage("stage1"){
      steps{
        script{
          some code
        }
        script{
          dynamicStage("stage2"){
            dynamicAlwaysScript{
              some code
            }
          }
        }
```

I checked in jenkins documentation, here or on google but don't find any information about those two keywords.

Does anyone know what those two keywords do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

After a good sleep I finally noticed this is a home-made function.

Thanks for reading